# Why is it wrong? about java 8 streaming

Tags: java, collections, java-8

```
public interface Filter<M> {

    boolean match(M m);

    public static <T> Collection<T> filter(Collection<T> collection, Filter<T> filter) {
        return collection.stream().filter(filter::match).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8));
        System.out.println(intList);

        List<Integer> list = filter(intList, null);

        System.out.println(list);
    }
}
```

[image: parameter type error]

I'm learning about java 8 streaming feature, and this is my problematic code...

I don't know why argument `intList` does not match `filter()` method. Java should know `<T>` is `Integer` here, right?

Comment: Please post your code *as code* rather than as a screenshot. The way you've done it here makes it much harder for us to reproduce the problem for ourselves.

Comment: As a side note: if you don’t modify `intList`, as in your code example, there is no need to wrap the result of `Arrays.asList` into an `ArrayList`, it *is* already a `List`. On the other hand, if you have a mutable list like `ArrayList` and you don’t need the original contents of `intList` anymore, there is `removeIf(Predicate)` on every `Collection` allowing an in-place filtering. In either case, you can simplify your code…

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not yet sure why you're getting that particular error, but the problem is that your method declares that it will return `Collection<T>`, but you're trying to assign the result to a `List<T>`. If you change the declaration of `filter` to:

```
public static <T> List<T> filter(Collection<T> collection, Filter<T> filter)
```

... then it compiles with no problems.

Comment: Yeah I changed `list` to `Collection<Integer>` and the error is gone too. It seems more like a return type error rather than a argument type error. Thanks.

Comment: he can also cast the result like this: `List<Integer> list = (List<Integer>) filter(intList, null);` With this solution he preserved the Collection return type for many other objects

Comment: @ManuZi: But that's a *weaker* solution - the method definitely returns a list, because it's using `Collectors.toList()`, so it makes sense to specify that it's returning a list...

Comment: @JonSkeet my fault i haven't seen it. Sorry, you absolutely right.